# SQL Server a single amount of rupees can check with three columns value its will deduct in sequence order

Tags: sql, sql-server

For example: the X amount is like 10.

The three columns are A,B,C

```
A  B    C
------------
5  1.5  0
--------------
```

First check the A column its greater than X so 10-5, remaining 5

So it checks with B column its greater than first remainder of 5, so 5-1.5=3.5

The final amount of 3.5

Set to C column value

Comment: why wouldn't you sum A, and B first, then evaluate if X is greater than AB, X - AB? Also what happens at any given point where X < AB? Would that be a refund, or just 'keep the change'?

Answer (score 0):

You could check to sum of `A` and `B` columns with `X` variable. `(A+B) < @X`

```
declare @X int = 10
update table1 set C = @X-(A+B) where (A+B) < @X
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/28fda/10)